# How to properly use edgemarts in Salesforce Wave dataflows?

Tags: einstein-analytics

I have a wave dataset called "CustomerData" which is populated from a salesforce custom object. What I want to do is take a snapshot of this custom object, and append it to the dataset (with today's date) as a part of the dataflow.

The problem I run in to is that I need to do an "edgemart" action followed by an "append" action to actually add data on to the exisitng dataset. However whenever I do this in my dataflow:

```
"ExistingCustomerDataSnapshots": {
      "action": "edgemart",
      "parameters": {
         "alias": "CustomerData"
      }
   },
```

I get this error when I run it:

> Error executing node ExistingCustomerDataSnapshots: Error in
>   GetEdgemartCurrentData for edgemart CustomerData: No edgemarts found
>   with specified URL:esObject/edgemart?current=true&alias=CustomerData

I am certain the dataset exists and that the name is correct.

Is there something I need to do additional to be able to use edgemarts besides just adding the action to the dataflow json?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?
I am also facing the same issue. Could you please help me in fixing this error?